# How "Data" can help me

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm doing a web game with javaScript and KnockoutJs library. 
In my html file I have a array foreach, and the number that this array saves, is the same number of buttons that a I have to draw on the page. Like this:

```
<strong data-bind = "foreach: cena1.opcoes">
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.teste">Opcão</button>
            <font color="red"><strong data-bind="text: conteudo"> </strong></font><br>
```

What I want to know is, how will I know which button the player selected?
I put data like a parameter on my button function, but I don't know how this works. like this:

```
object.teste = function(data) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` binding passes the current item to the bound function.

```js
var vm = {
  items: [1, 2, 3],
  click: function(data) {
    alert('You clicked: ' + data);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
  <button data-bind="click:$parent.click">Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the function this way:

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { $parent.teste($data); }">Opcão</button>
```

or

```
    <button data-bind="click: function() { $parent.teste($data/* here can be any arguments available in the current binding context */); }">Opcão</button>
```

## Update

By default the first parameter is being passed to the click handler function is the current view model - $data in the current binding context.

For more details and advanced scenarios you can check the [Knockout JS documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).